# How can I use $_SESSION on Drupal Webform?

Tags: php, session, drupal, drupal-7, session-cookies

I'm using Drupal 7 and Webform module. And I want show to users, input's previous text. How can I use session on Drupal?

Comment: Show your code. What you have actually tried?

Comment: I have not tried anything because I do not know which way to follow. this is a Q&A website and always trying something we do not ask questions here. We do not have any resources on the internet about this topic, I have to ask such a question here. Please help if you are going to be an obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use 2 hooks

1. hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
2. hook_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission)

In `hook_webform_submission_insert` you set session, and in `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` set field default value from session.

Cheers!!!